# Why am I getting random result on item click in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Why am I getting random result on item click? My error is inside the btn onClick Listener but what shows in my TextView (reference_number) is fine. when button clicked - it will open another activity to show more details about it but it shows random result, after I scroll my recyclerView it will change the result again. @@ im confused already, below is all the codes inside my Adapter

What's the cause of this error and where did I get this wrong?

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    int i;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_history_pending, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        i = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        holder.reference_number.setText("#"+mainActivity.myBookings.getCargoBooking().get(i).getReferenceNumber());

        holder.btn_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String fee;
                fee = isNull(mainActivity.myBookings.getCargoBooking().get(i).getCargoItem().get(0).getCargoFee().toString());

                Intent i = new Intent(mainActivity.context, BookingDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("fee", fee);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private String isNull(String s){
        if (s != null){
            return s;
        } else return "";
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mainActivity.myBookings.getCargoBooking().size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView reference_number, driver_schedule;
        Button btn_details;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            reference_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pending_trackNum);
            driver_schedule = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view_driver_schedule);
            btn_details = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pending_view);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the "i" variable in your adapter scope, remove it and declare it as local (inside your onBindViewHolder method) and it should work.

Comment: oh i see, I think I just got too scared to use the final int i variable and put it outside. I thought it will make the 'i' = 0 for the whole length of my list. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your instance variable `i` keeps changing whenever `onBindViewHolder` is called, say when the `RecyclerView` is being scrolled for example. Instead, change the variable `i` to local:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final int i = holder.getAdapterPosition();
```